# Aura Attribute access change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura-attribute

We encountered this issue "You can't set access to 'private' on attributes 'fields' because this component is referenced by Lightning Page: 'Record Page'" when trying to save an aura component with a change to an attribute access (public to private).

We have implemented the interfaces:

- force:hasRecordId
- flexipage:availableForRecordHome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had implemented the aura interfaces force:hasRecordId and flexipage:availableForRecordHome and I believe Salesforce is interpreting the "fields" attribute name as a variable populated by the interface (such as recordId).

To fix you can change the attribute name and access at the same time and it will allow the component to be saved.